# angular 9 interceptor on lazy mode

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, angular-module, angular9

I have bought [lorax angular template](https://themeforest.net/item/lorax-angular-7-admin-dashboard-template/23430042) which developed in angular and updated version 9. I try to modify that template for my require and need to add HTTP_INTERCEPTOR to my project.

This template has many module and I create for myself too. Let me share some code on my project.

> APP.MODULE.TS

```
    import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
    /*
    Also Imported necessary libraries
    */
        const DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG: PerfectScrollbarConfigInterface = {
          suppressScrollX: true,
          wheelPropagation: false
        };
        
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        PageLoaderComponent,
        SidebarComponent,
        RightSidebarComponent,
        SimpleDialogComponent,
        DialogformComponent,
        BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet,
      ],
      imports: [
        /*
IMPORTS SOME OTHER COMPONENT
*/
        SatPopoverModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: 'apiURL', useValue: 'http://localhost:8080' },
        { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
        { provide: PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG, useValue: DEFAULT_PERFECT_SCROLLBAR_CONFIG },
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: AuthRequestOption,
          multi: true
        },
        DynamicScriptLoaderService,
        RightSidebarService,
        WINDOW_PROVIDERS
      ],
      entryComponents: [
        SimpleDialogComponent,
        DialogformComponent,
        BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

And I have "YONETICI" module with routes itself.

> yonetici.module.ts

```
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
/*Also Imported necessary libraries*/

@NgModule({
  declarations: [KullaniciListComponent, InlineEditComponent, KullaniciList2Component],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    YoneticiRoutingModule,
    DataTablesModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    SatPopoverModule,
    MatInputModule,
    TablesRoutingModule,
    NgxDatatableModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ]
})
export class YoneticiModule { }
```

and my interceptor file is:

> auth-request-option.ts

```
import {MyApiService, TOKEN_NAME} from './yonetici/my-api.service';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpHeaders, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

import { from as fromPromise, Observable} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class AuthRequestOption implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor( private cookieService: MyApiService ) {
console.log('intercepting');
  }
  getCookie(){
    return this.cookieService.getToken();
  }
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if(this.getCookie() !== null){
      const jsonReq: HttpRequest<any> = req.clone({
        setHeaders:{
          Authorization : 'Bearer 213123' //this is getting from servis
        }
      });
      console.log('intercepted1');
      return next.handle(jsonReq);
    }else{
      console.log('intercepted2');
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

And finally when i try to post(or get) method to localhost:8080/yonetici/kullanici_list to java sevis i got this messages in Chrome Consoles:

```
*intercepting
*main.js:488 intercepted1
*main.js:488 intercepted1
*vendor.js:312988 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/yonetici/kullanici_list' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
*polyfills.js:3050 GET http://localhost:8080/yonetici/kullanici_list net::ERR_FAILED
```

Also When i debug code on server side, I got non "Authorization" header. And no "Bearer " code.
I spent two days on that error. really need your help...

Comment: This looks like a CORS issue, as mentioned in the error message. Have you set CORS up on your back end?

Comment: @KurtHamilton yes in backend i add @CrossOrigin(origins = "h t t p : / / localhost:4200") to in controller(without empty space characters)

Comment: Can you test your code against a public API that you know accepts cross origin requests? Then you can isolate the problem to either your code or your backend